# Unexpected = error message

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working inside of code igniter and thought this if statement would go through but its giving me a unexpected = error.

```
if($title !=== FALSE){

} else{

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Should be:

```
if ($title !== FALSE)
```

Answer (score 8):

You have too many equals signs

try:

```
if($title !== FALSE){
```

Comment: +1 because I didn't get the other answer, they looked the same to me before I read yours :D

Answer (score 3):

What is **!===**? I guess you should use **!==** or **!=**.